# static memory in functions [PHP]

Tags: php, static-variables

I have research function with static variable, lets look the next code:

*(Warning! For test you must have enabled xdebug in php.ini)*

```
function a()
{
    static $var = 10;
    xdebug_debug_zval('var');
    return $var;
}
a();
```

It's output the next: `var:(refcount=2, is_ref=1),int 10`

What's going on? Why is `refcount=2`? Where second reference?

P.S So if we have `var:(refcount=2, is_ref=1),int 10`. It's means why we can't save reference in static variable.

**For the user Mark Baker**

```
function a()
{
    $var = 10;
    xdebug_debug_zval('var');
    return $var;
}
a();
```

Outputs: `var:(refcount=1, is_ref=0),int 10`

Info: Calling a function does not use the variable argument that no problems with outputting information. Therefore, in view of arguments used by name of the variable written into a string

Comment: @MarkBaker I updated my post

Comment: @MarkBaker That's wrong. `debug_zval_dump()` takes input by reference. `xdebug_debug_zval()` however is internally accessing it directly from parent symbol table without manipulating refcount and references.

Comment: @bwoebi - Ah! My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to static variables in PHP creates a reference to an internal array of statics upon usage.

You can verify this by noticing that it is impossible to store references in static variables:

```
function a() {
    static $var = 1;
    var_dump($var);
    $var = &$ref;
    $var = 2;
}
a(); a();
// prints int(1) int(1)
```

Comment: Ha, I know that you can not store references to static variables, I tested it. Can I know a second alias static variable? Or can i see internal array of statics?

Comment: @MaximPro [`(new ReflectionFunction("a"))->getStaticVariables()`](http://php.net/reflectionfunctionabstract.getstaticvariables) will give you them. Not sure what you mean with "second alias"?

Comment: No, I do not need an array of static variables in a function! See the next: `var:(refcount=2, is_ref=1)` - here we are have `refcount=2` and `is_ref=1` it means what we are have a hardlink. First link-variable is `var` and where is a second link-variable? I want to know where she is?

Comment: Very interesting! I tested next code: `$obj = new ReflectionFunction('a');`
`$obj->getStaticVariables()['var'] = 777;`
`a();`
But I could not affect the value of the array, why?

Comment: @MaximPro because it's a copy of the internal state, without references ;-) There's no way to manipulate it externally.

Comment: What about my first comment above you?

Comment: @MaximPro as said, the other variable is an entry in the internal array. You won't be ever able to access it directly.

Comment: That is no way to get access to the source array? I am right?

Comment: @MaximPro Yes; That's what I just said ;o)

Comment: Okay, if you really do not have any way to get this array - sadly. But this is a good answer why the links are not stored static =)

Comment: I'll wait a couple of days, maybe someone else will be able to answer in more detail. If someone does not answer I will give you the answer. Ok?

Comment: @MaximPro I give you the detail… You just need to ask for which details you want. I'm not going to explain the whole engine to you, so that you can pick the details you were interested in. Already your last question (the one with the bounty) was imprecise in that way.